# Is it too late to submit bug fixes to texlive 2024?

Tags: texlive

I saw that texlive 2024 is released on march 13th, is it too late to submit bug fixes to some packages so that they end-up in texlive 2024?

Comment: Depends on what the issue is. For things like the LaTeX kernel, packages, documentation, etc., they take updates year-round, so any time is fine. The TeX Live binaries (`luatex`, `pdftex`, `dvisvgm`, etc.) are frozen now, so feature requests will need to wait until next year. Bugs in the binaries is a little more complicated—something really minor will need to wait until next year, but anything major can certainly be fixed now.

Comment: for 2024 it doesn't matter much when you submit an update, but if you want the fix to be also in the final texlive 2023 you should hurry.

Comment: See this mail: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2024-March/050185.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just updated my packages (Max: I meant package libraries). Hopefully, it will get in!